# directx/directshow preparesurface fail / fail to present image

Tags: c#, c++, video, directx, directshow

What is the common cause of a 887601c2 error?
As seen below
-2005532222 (887601c2)

I have a program written in directshow that captures a TV tuner device an renders it.

Found capture device: 'Hauppage Cx23100 Video Capture'
FAILED TO PRESENT IMAGE: 887601c2
PrepareSurface failed [-2005532222]
Found capture device: 'Hauppage Cx23100 Video Capture'
FAILED TO PRESENT IMAGE: 887601c2
PrepareSurface failed [-2005532222]

On a later day:
Found capture device: 'Hauppage Cx23100 Video Capture'
GetFrame failed [887601c2]
Could not get frame
PrepareSurface failed [-2005532222]
GetFrame failed [887601c2]
Could not get frame
GetFrame failed [887601c2]
Could not get frame
GetFrame failed [887601c2]
Could not get frame
GetFrame failed [887601c2]
Could not get frame

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is 0x887601C2 `DDERR_SURFACELOST`. The error is apparently related to video presentation, either loss of resources such that with desktop lock or concurrent application operation, or might also be related to misconfiguration on a multi-monitor system.

See [DirectShow return hresult 0x887601C2 on IMediaControl.Run()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21320350/directshow-return-hresult-0x887601c2-on-imediacontrol-run) for possible cause.